# How to make a selection of blocks disappear in a fade effect

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I'm building a TARDIS (Doctor Who's Time Machine) in Minecraft, and for when it disembarks, it fades away. Is there any practical way i can do this in Minecraft or should i make a texture pack?

Reference -

P.S - I have all the sounds ready, that's not the problem.

Comment: figure out most of it on your own, and when you get suck on a certain part, ask for help, not guidence

Comment: This is not possible. The best you could do is replacing them with blocks with custom textures that have more transparency.

Comment: Suppose you replace all the blocks with colored stained glass, then replace those with colored dust particles? If that could work I could answer this for you a way on how to do it.

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition is being played.

Comment: Agreed. I'd gladly vote to reopen when we know what platform this is for.

Answer (score 1):

In Minecraft, particle effects are used instead of Texture fading in order to show transition because physical block opacity is binary, and using texture changes for fading a block would be demanding for Minecraft to have without modification.

I would recommend either masking a /setblock transition with a multitude of particles, or, like you said, use multiple /setblock transitions with increasingly transparent textures. Plus, if you already have a custom TARDIS resource pack, you already possess most of the skills required to do the second option. GL! I hope this helps.